# How to store each response from a loop of multiple API calls in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to make an API call in a loop with an array of IDs and store the response of each API call into a variable as an array.

```
const myIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19]

 forkJoin(
    myIds.map((i: number) => 
      this.http.get('apicallwith/${i}')
      .subscribe(res) => {
        const allResponses = [...res];
        console.log(allResponses) // always getting the response of my first ID
      }
    )
  )
```

I tried forkJoin from what I understood and not sure where I'm doing wrong

Comment: forkJoin create an unique observable. You has write bad the parenthesis: `forkJoin(myIds.map((i:number)=>this.http.get('apicallwidth/'+i))).subscribe((res:any[])=>{console.log(res)})`. In two steps: `obs$=forkJoin(myIds.map((i:number)=>this.http.get('apicallwidth/'+i)))`; `obs$.subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `combineLatest` here is example

```typescript
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
const myIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19]
combineLatest(myIds.map(id => this.http.get('apicallwith/${id}')))
.subscribe((values)=>{
   console.log(values)
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Mostafa combineLatest works to get each and every response but can you update your solution to save them all into a single array.

Comment: it is already single array of response >>> pelase describe the shape that you want 
the result now [res1,res2,res3] tell me what shape you need and i will try my best to solve it

Comment: console.log gives me for using id: 1 and 2 >>>> [{user:'tom',id:1}] and [{user:'jerry',id:2}] instead I need it as [{user:'tom',id:1}, {user:'jerry',id:2}]

Comment: if you have teamViewer let us meet to check please

Comment: nothing to share anyway thanks. I'll try to figure it out

Comment: It's not necessary to use `combineLatest`.  In your sample code, you can replace `combineLatest` with `forkJoin` and it will still work.

Comment: @imPK or you can use `Promise.all([myIds.map(id => this.http.get('apicallwith/${id}'))]).then((data) => {})`. data return single array

Answer (score 1):

The reason `forkJoin` wasn't working for you is that you were calling `subscribe` inside the `map`, which means you were passing an array of Subscriptions instead of an array of Observables (*I would think TS would warn you about that*).

The following would work using `forkJoin`:

```
forkJoin(myIds.map(i => this.http.get('apicallwith/${i}'))).subscribe(
    res => {
        const allResponses = [...res];
        console.log(allResponses)
    }
);
```